# Python cv2.WarpPerspective tranfromation shows Dashed line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I took the two dummy destination points pts2 and pts4 with four coordinates and implemented wrap perspective transformation twice. Then output for those points has a Dashed line in between.

```
Python Code 

warped_mask = np.zeros((480,640,3),dtype="uint8") 
h_base, w_base = 480,640

white_subject =  np.ones((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")*255
h_white, w_white = white_subject.shape[:2]


pts2 = np.float32([[20, 20], [100, 20], [150, 300], [20, 250]])
pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_white, 0], [w_white, h_white], [0, h_white]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 

pts4 = np.float32([[100, 20],[300,20], [300, 300], [150, 300]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts4)
warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 

cv2.imshow("canvas", warped_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Dotted Line Between the output]

Input Subject as design image

[image]

Ouptput

[image]

Please help me out in getting the smooth stitched without a dotted line.

Comment: a "hairline". generally not avoidable.

Comment: You could try openGL texturing instead of homography warping, (depends on your goal whether that makes sense or not). Do you really want to / have to stitch along a single line? If yes, make sure that every pixel is available in one of both input images. In many tasks you will instead have an overlap, where pixels are available in both input images. There you can use cross-blending or decide to use one of both values.

Comment: The objective is to implement the non-affine transformation such that the output doesn't have the dotted line at the edges. For reference visit this repo https://github.com/GSNCodes/Image_Overlaying_Using_Perspective_Transform

Answer (score 2):

The dashed line is a result of arithmetic **overflow**.

When zooming in, we can see that all the values are positive, but some are not 0 and not 255:
[image]

When summing (for example): `uint8(255) + uint8(56)` in NumPy, the result is `55` due to overflow.
Pixel value of BGR = `(55, 55, 55)` is viewed as dark gray.

---

In the white mask example, we want to get `255` when adding positive value to `255`.

For avoiding overflow, you may use `cv.add` instead of `+=`.
`cv.add` has an overflow protection (it clips the result to 255).

Replace `warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base))` with:

```
warped_mask = cv2.add(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))
```

Result when using: `cv2.add`:
[image]

---

When using the pattern, the result is better when using `cv2.max` instead of `cv2.add`.

Replace `warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base))` with:

```
warped_mask = cv2.max(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))
```

---

Result using pattern and `cv2.max`:
[image]

---

Complete code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

warped_mask = np.zeros((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")
h_base, w_base = 480,640

#white_subject =  np.ones((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")*255
white_subject = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('pattern.jpg'), (640, 480))
h_white, w_white = white_subject.shape[:2]


pts2 = np.float32([[20, 20], [100, 20], [150, 300], [20, 250]])
pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_white, 0], [w_white, h_white], [0, h_white]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
#warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 
warped_mask = cv2.max(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))

pts4 = np.float32([[100, 20],[300,20], [300, 300], [150, 300]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts4)

#warped_mask += cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 
warped_mask = cv2.max(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))

cv2.imshow("canvas", warped_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

For better result, we may add padding:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

warped_mask = np.zeros((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")
h_base, w_base = 480, 640

white_subject = np.ones((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")*255
white_subject = cv2.imread('pattern.jpg')
h_white, w_white = white_subject.shape[:2]

padded_warped_mask = np.pad(warped_mask, ((1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)), mode='edge')
padded_white_subject = np.pad(white_subject, ((1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)), mode='edge')

pts2 = np.float32([[20, 20], [100, 20], [150, 300], [20, 250]])
pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_white, 0], [w_white, h_white], [0, h_white]])


# Transform (0,0) coordinate to (1,1)
top2one = np.float64([[1,    0,   -1],
                      [0,    1,   -1],
                      [0,    0,    1]])

# Transform (1,1) coordinate to (0,0)
one2top = np.float64([[1,      0,    1],
                      [0,      1,    1],
                      [0,      0,    1]])


transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)

# Compensate the transformation for applying the padded two rows and columns
#transformation_matrix_white = one2top @ transformation_matrix_white @ top2one
transformation_matrix_white = top2one @ transformation_matrix_white @ one2top

#warped_mask = cv2.add(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(padded_white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))
warped_mask = cv2.max(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(padded_white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))

pts4 = np.float32([[100, 20],[300,20], [300, 300], [150, 300]])



transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts4)

# Compensate the transformation for applying the padded two rows and columns
#transformation_matrix_white = one2top @ transformation_matrix_white @ top2one
transformation_matrix_white = top2one @ transformation_matrix_white @ one2top

#warped_mask = cv2.add(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(padded_white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))
warped_mask = cv2.max(warped_mask, cv2.warpPerspective(padded_white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)))

cv2.imshow("canvas", warped_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried on a higher dimension, i.e warped_mask = np.zeros((1000,1000,3),dtype="uint8")
h_base, w_base = 1000,1000 , for different dummy points i.e pts2 = np.float32([[20, 20], [200, 20], [450, 700], [20, 250]]) and pts4 = np.float32([[200, 20],[500,20], [700, 700], [450, 700]]) I got the dotted line in the result.

Comment: In what configuration? With padding or without padding? Using white subject or pattern? Please note that the answer applies only specific cases - it's not supposed to be a general solution that covers all cases.

Comment: I used it without padding with pattern .

Comment: Try with padding. Why did you try it only without padding?

Comment: Tried the padded approach, the decrease the black dashed line but doesn't remove it completely. Could you elaborate on the significance of the top2one  and one2top variables?